# Command is available as user, but not sudo?

Tags: 12.04, bash, make

I am in the process of building gendev, a sega genesis development environment and I am running into an interesting problem.

When I try to install via "sudo make install" I get an error stating that a program named "rescomp" is not found, see below:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/bubo/Genesis-Dev/gendev-read-only/sgdk/sgdk-read-only'
rescomp res/libres.res res/libres.s
make[1]: rescomp: Command not found
make[1]: *** [res/libres.s] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bubo/Genesis-Dev/gendev-read-only/sgdk/sgdk-read-only'
make: *** [sgdk-read-only/libmd.a] Error 2
```

However, if I return to being a normal user (not root) I can execute the rescomp program without issues. Is this a problem with environment variables? How can I enable the root account to use "rescomp" as well?

Comment: where is rescomp? or better yet `whereis rescomp` Most likely it's not in a place that is the sudo's PATH

Comment: That is exactly what the issue was, the user's path variable was not the same as root's

Comment: Post what you did to fix it as an answer, if you have. Others will find it useful when running into the same problem. Not necessarily this exact situation, but still applies.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the original "make" only modified the user's PATH environment variable and not root's!

I found this out by using the command:

```
printenv
```

on each account and then I noticed the different path variables, from there I modified the root path by logging in as a root user and issuing the following:

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Where /usr/games and /usr/local/games were the two directories that were missing!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check with `which command` as user where the path points to.

Check back if that command path is in your `PATH` as root.